# How to change app store promotion image for in-app purchase?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app and the app has one in-app purchase that I implemented the app store promotion with promotional image and code, and the promotion is enabled in the app store.

Now I want to change the promotional image. so I uploaded a new image and create a new version. The new version is released in the App Store, however, the promotional image is still the old one.

In the App Store Promotions page of App Store Connect, the new image has a yellow border, and when I hover over it shows:

> We will review the new promotional image before we make it available on the App Store.

But when will the new image be reviewed, how can I submit it to review?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer? I have the same problem. The new version released 3 days ago but In-Apps Purchases still not being reviewed.

Comment: Sorry, I forget. It just somehow managed to update.

Comment: Thank you. I think I found a solution. You may try next time. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution, I'll try next time and if it works I'll accept your answer. but it rarely happens, need to update the promote image XD.

Comment: Hi Alen, did you change your images recently? I just updated on the last version. And writing a comment on Release Notes worked again. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** I found a manual solution and it worked twice. Before submitting a new version. Add a text on *App Review Information -> Notes* like: *We changed In-App Purchases Promotional images. Can you please review them?* If they approve then images will change with the new version.

**Support:** I asked to Apple support. They replied like this. But, I couldn't find any solution here. Just wanted to share.

[image: ticket]

Link 1: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev8b5cb82e2

Link 2: https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/